# Can I Temporarily toggle novalidate through a button in HTML5 for saving a form's current state

Tags: html, validation, client

I'm using Django and I created a form that I want to submit when fully completed but also have the options (tied to it's own button) to save the current state of the form. I can bypass the validation on Django's serverside check but HTML's client validation is a different beast. Is there a way I can toggle on and off `novalidate` in HTML5 (e.g. when a button is pressed)?